# How do I take an address variable and put another variable into that cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have found the intersect address for a cell and applied it to a string variable (EE). now I am trying to apply UEquip (a variable) value to that cell (EE). I cannot figure how to do that.

I have applied UEquip to cell P20 and tried to make P20 equal EE but it won't work. Set didn't work and with didn't do it either. Errors Object required is common.

Below is the basis for this.

```
Public Sub Upgrade_Click()
Dim UEquip As Variant
Dim EE As String

'EE is the address of the cell that needs to be changed by user input.
EE = Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Range("E1").EntireColumn).Address

'Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip is the user input
'Range("p20").Value is a hold spot because i couldnt get it to work in 'other code of the general type
Range("p20").Value = Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip

EE.Value = Range("p20")

End Sub
```

Comment: You've already made `P20` equal to something on the preceding step. To make it equal to `EE`, you use:`Range("p20").Value = EE`. But why you want to do this is unclear.

Comment: Maybe `Selection.EntireRow.Columns("E").value = Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip`

Comment: So Mybe i didnt explain it well, sorry. EE is the cell that needs to be changed based upon the search criteria they did. Getting EE's address i now need to change the cell that is EE with the new value in P20 or Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip either one would work as they are the same.

Comment: Then maybe `Range(Selection.EntireRow.Columns("E").value) = Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip`

Comment: Tim - Wouldn't that change all of E Column to Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip

Comment: Tried it - Run time error 1004 Method range of object global failed

Comment: `EE` is a string, not a range object. So try `Range(EE).Value = Range("p20").Value` or maybe `Range(EE).Value = Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip`

Comment: EE is a string because of the .address, I figured that out. The Range(EE).Value = Range("p20").Value is giving me the Run time error 1004 Method range of object global failed. The Range(EE).Value = Phone_Upgrade_Form.UEquip gives me the same.

Comment: What is an example of the actual values in Column E?  Just so we're all on the same page here.

Comment: `Selection.EntireRow.Columns("E")` is only the cell(s) in column E for the selected rows(s).

Comment: @Alienjester I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. When your macro stops, what does `Locals` window show for the value of `EE`?

Comment: Tim - For that column is: Equipment -Samsung - Google - 8 - Atari - IPhone.  But that is for that specific column. After i get that working it would be for a total of 8 columns each with different info: Text,Numbers,Dates,Emails

Comment: Ron - I don't know what Locals is. Still really new to all this. When I hover over it, it is showing EE=Empty

Comment: @Alienjester Check the View option on the main menu bar at the top of the VBE. Ensure you have enabled the `Locals` window. But `EE` should not be showing `Empty`. It might be showing `""` or an address. If the former, then your `Intersect` function is not returning anything and would explain the error message. Perhaps what you think is selected is not really Selected.

Comment: OK so I do the search on one userform  then the results userform will pop up from there they select if they want to upgrade the information in the boxes by selecting the upgrade button. When they select the upgrade button it does the intersect for the selection(search) and the columns they have the option of changing. It saves that cell from the intersect in EE at that time. Then a userform pops up where they can change the information as needed. when they hit the save button it is supposed to pull the EE Cell and change it to the new info. That last part is not working.

Comment: I don't think it is pulling the EE from before the userform shows up where they change the info. The locals show Expression - +ME - EE, Value - Empty, Type - Phone_Upgrade_Form/Phone_Upgrade_Form - Varient/Empty

Comment: When I hover over where the intersect is done I get EE = "$E$5"

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to do it all under the same userform then EE was able to save to be put into the new range.